# Getting a JSON Object from a JSON Array isn't working

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am trying to get JSON data from a JSON array which looks like this:

```
{
"common": [
    {
        "food_name": "eggs",
        "serving_unit": "large",
        "tag_name": "raw eggs",
        "serving_qty": 1,
        "common_type": null,
        "tag_id": "775",
        "photo": {
            "thumb": "https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/775_thumb.jpg"
        },
        "locale": "en_US"
    },
```

Here's what I am using:

```
    public class GetDietData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String calories = "UNDEFINED";
        try {

            URL urlForGetRequest = new URL("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?query=egg");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("x-app-key", "REMOVED");
            connection.addRequestProperty("x-app-id", "REMOVED");

            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputString;
            while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(inputString);
            }


            JSONObject jsonRes = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray common = jsonRes.getJSONArray("common");

            for (int i=0; i<common.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObj = common.getJSONObject(i);

                 calories = jsonObj.getString("food_name");

            }

            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            editText=(findViewById(R.id.editTextDiet));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return calories;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String calories) {

        if (calories == "UNDEFINED") {
            Toast.makeText(Diet.this, "Food not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            editText=(findViewById(R.id.editTextDiet));
            editText.setText(calories);
        }


    }
}
```

I have the following problem:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for common
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
```

So the problem seems to be that the "common" array has no value, hence it cannot find it's length? I'm unsure as to why it cannot see the "common" array as i have looked at numerous other questions about getting Objects from Arrays and I have replicated the code identically each time but with the same result. If I use solely a JSONObject and ignore the full array I can see in the stacktrace that it is attempting to download the whole array into that object which means it's definitely not something wrong with the GET request or the API keys.
Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using Volley or Retrofit than AsyncTask, by the way

Comment: I'm quite a beginner still so can't manage that just yet. :(

Comment: Alright, well, the code doesn't look wrong other than you're not logging out the value that's trying to get parsed

Comment: Simple fix really. You never add the string from the response to the 'JSONObject' object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error you are getting is because you aren't passing the String response to `jsonObject` so it can't find any thing in an empty object

the fix is

```
String inputString;
while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         builder.append(inputString);
       }

        JSONObject jsonRes = new JSONObject(inputString); \\this is the fix 
        JSONArray common = jsonRes.getJSONArray("common");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however now it's crashing with error:
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Surely this shouldn't be null?

Comment: try `JSONObject jsonRes = new JSONObject(builder.toString());` as you should pass your string here as it's `StringBuilder` or `String`

Comment: That worked!(kind of) it seems to retrieve the very last item in the json list but I can sort that out from here i think. Thank you very much for your help.